# Word with both hard and soft “c” sound, meaning an intrinsic dislike of rules

Tags: single-word-requests

I am finding myself totally unable to remember a word. It’s like having an itch in my brain!

The word itself has both a hard and a soft *c* (I often use it along with *placate* and *façade* to demonstrate hard and soft c’s). It means an intrinsic dislike or distrust of rules, a propensity to go against them, or both.

(I had originally thought that it began *inc-* but after taking a look at [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=words%20beginning%20inc) list I'm not so sure anymore.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no practical value as a question to anyone other than the poster, who now has the answer he sought.

Answer (score 5):

**Recalcitrant** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recalcitrant)

> *adjective* stubbornly refusing to obey rules or orders
>   *"the manager worried that the recalcitrant employee would try to undermine his authority"*

Answer (score 2):

**Contumacious** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contumacious)

> *adjective* Obstinately disobedient or rebellious; insubordinate.